# Historical reference to the group cohomology of the integers mod 4

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, math-history, group-cohomology

I am looking for a historical reference for the first calculation of the group cohomology of the integers mod 4, or perhaps finite cyclic groups. I know that already in his 1953 paper in the Comment. Math. Helv, volume 27, "Cohomologie modulo 2 des complexes d'Eilenberg-MacLane" J. P. Serre said it was well known. Section 11 starts with:

> L'algèbre $H^* (Z_m ; 1, Z_2)$ n'est pas autre chose que l'algèbre de cohomologie modulo 2 du >groupe $Z_m$, au sens de Hopf. Sa structure est bien connue (on peut la déterminer soit >algébriquement, soit en utilisant les espaces lenticulaires)

Does anyone know of something older?